# No TypeTag available for a case class using scala 3 with spark 3

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-3, spark3

I have my code that runs a spark job with scala 3

```
@main def startDatasetJob(): Unit =
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("Datasets")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()

  case class CarRow(Name: String,
                 Miles_per_Gallon: Double,
                 Cylinders: Long,
                 Displacement: Double,
                 Horsepower: Long,
                 Weight_in_lbs: Long,
                 Acceleration: Double,
                 Year: Date,
                 Origin: String
                )

  implicit val carEncoder: Encoder[CarRow] = Encoders.product[CarRow]
  val carsDF = spark.read
    .format("json")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .load("src/main/resources/data/cars.json")

  val carDS = carsDF.as[CarRow]
```

but get the error message

```
No TypeTag available for CarRow
  implicit val carEncoder: Encoder[CarRow] = Encoders.product[CarRow]
```

get a bit confused why the compiler seems unable to load the case class, if any one can help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73836319/scala-spark-encoders-productx-where-x-is-a-case-class-keeps-giving-me-no-ty https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74249859/spark-df-astype-fails-to-compile https://github.com/VirtusLab/iskra https://github.com/vincenzobaz/spark-scala3 https://github.com/zio/zio-quill/tree/master/quill-spark/src

Answer (score 3):

Spark's encoder derivation relies on Scala 2.x mechanisms, some of them no longer exist.

Have you tried with [spark-scala3](https://github.com/vincenzobaz/spark-scala3)? It provides the encoder derivation for Scala 3.

```scala
libraryDependencies += "io.github.vincenzobaz" %% "spark-scala3" % "0.1.3"
```

Then

```scala
import scala3encoders.given
```

(see the examples in the repo)